# The result to target fragment seems to be null after rotate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, rotation

I am developing a game. I have a game fragment and a rule fragment. First of, the game activity starts the game fragment with no rule:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new GameFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    }
```

In the game fragment, i can start the rule fragment:

```
            RuleFragment ruleFragment = new RuleFragment();

            ruleFragment.setTargetFragment(GameFragment.this, RULE_FRAGMENT);

            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            //Sets the list of previously played rounds as an argument for the new fragment
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelableArrayList(ROUNDS_PLAYED, mRounds);
            ruleFragment.setArguments(b);

            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, ruleFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I can return to the game fragment like this:

```
if(ruleIsSelected && mRound != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(CHOSEN_RULE, mRound);
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
```

My issue are, I can start the rule fragment from the game fragment both in landscape mode as well as in portrait mode, and the return a result with no problem through an intent. But when I am in the rule fragment AND THEN rotate the screen, nothing seems to work. The button I press to return to the game still works, but no new Rule object seems to be chosen. In my game fragment I have:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RULE_FRAGMENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Round chosenRule = data.getParcelableExtra(RuleFragment.CHOSEN_RULE);
            if (chosenRule != null) {
                mActiveRound = chosenRule;
                setThrowsLeftTextView(mActiveRound.getThrowsLeft());
                mRounds.add(mActiveRound);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I don't rotate, everything works as a charm. But when I rotate in the rule fragment, the setThrowsLeftTextView(...) method gives me a null-pointer. Remember, that method does work when I don't rotate.

In veeery short; if fragment A starts fragment B, and then I rotate the screen, how do I send data (an object) from B to A and set a TextView in A representing an attribute of what I sent from B (e.g. a number)?